# Format thousands separator

Tags: c++, mfc

I am programming in c++ using mfc in visual studio 2010.

I live in Europe, so I have the regional settings of the PC not USA but Europe.

I use the .Format function of CString to print the result of a calculation and I want to add a decimal point as separator between hundred and thousands.

For example, I would like to have displayed 23.400 instead of 23400

Is it possible using a particular formatting of % or i have to change the setting of the pc?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know CString's `.Format` doesn't support this.

I'd use a `stringstream` to handle the formatting:

```
std::ostringstream temp;
temp.imbue(std::locale(""));

temp << 23400;

CString result = temp.str().c_str();
```

Specifying an empty string as the name of the locale as I've done here means it should pick up the locale setting from the OS. You can give the name of a specific locale instead (e.g., if you want a specific locale, regardless of how the OS is configured):

```
temp.imbue(std::locale("de")); // German locale
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is what your are looking for. Simple search on google gave the answer. This type of print (`%.2f`) by the way is pretty standard among pretty much every modern language.

`"Floating point: %.2f\n"`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa314327(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: The '%.2f' format characters mean to display only 2 decimal number. It is not what i asked. I want a . as separator between tousand and hundred, not integer and decimal